# Rails, Imap Oauth & Access Token Refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, imap

I'm writing a bespoke backup solution for a client, i can authenticate and retrieve email no bother. The issue occurs when the access token expires, and I use the refresh token to get a new access token, this works fine, but then i hit the issue, I need to continue fetching the messages, but i get a imap error
`vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/net-imap-0.4.6/lib/net/imap.rb:2569:in                                                                           get_tagged_response': Session invalidated - AccessTokenExpired (Net::IMAP::ByeResponseError)`
I have checked that the new access token has been created and expires at a future date/time
So then i call
`imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2',customer_email,customer_access_token)`
but i get the above error.
I didn't create a new imap with `imap = Net::IMAP.new` . So i'm wondering if you can't reuse the imap object, but have to create a new one or if there's a way to reset the errors.

Comment: You can .debug=true and see.

Comment: Unless it disconnects when you authenticate, probably not. IMAP, generally, does not allow you to reauthenticate an existing connection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @arnt and @Max for your comments

After further research it doesn't allow you to reuse the object, so you have to use imap = Net::IMAP.new